# signing key using Oracle PL/SQL and pass to google maps api

Tags: oracle, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, oracle-sqldeveloper

I wantto generate Cryptographic signing key using Oracle 10g Database(i dont have any java ,vb or some lang to generate it).
    I am using the below code (copyed from OTN) but the key provided by google and returned by below code is not matchenter code hereing. not sure why. did lot of triles but non of them are worked...

```
enter code here

DECLARE
l_key_src VARCHAR2(100) := 'ssssssssssssssssssssss';  

l_key_b64 varchar2(100) := translate(l_key_src,'-_','+/');

l_key_bin raw(2000);

l_string VARCHAR2(1000) := utl_url.escape('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-15.800514,-47.91378&' || 'zoom=11&' || 'size=300x300&' || 'sensor=false&' || 'client=zzzzzzzzzz');

l_sig_mac RAW(2000);
l_base64_sig_mac VARCHAR2(2000);
l_base64_sig_mac_alter VARCHAR2(2000);

BEGIN

l_key_bin := utl_encode.base64_decode(UTL_I18N.string_to_raw(l_key_b64, 'AL32UTF8'));

l_sig_mac :=DBMS_CRYPTO.mac(UTL_I18N.string_to_raw(l_string, 'AL32UTF8'), DBMS_CRYPTO.hmac_sh1,l_key_bin);


l_base64_sig_mac := UTL_RAW.cast_to_varchar2(UTL_ENCODE.base64_encode(l_sig_mac));

l_base64_sig_mac_alter := translate(l_base64_sig_mac,'+/','-_');

dbms_output.put_line(l_string);
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('MAC Signature (Base64-encoded): ' || l_base64_sig_mac_alter); 

END;
```

Comment: any help please sugget if this can be possible????